# Angular2 and jQuery DataTables

Tags: javascript, angular, dynamic, datatables

I've added Angular 2 to an older application which primarily was built using jQuery + plugins. I'm trying to use jQuery [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) inside of a Component. I can get it to load the table just fine. The problem is that I have a cell template that has NG2 event listeners. In Angular 1 I could use the $compile service to register them to the scope, but that's gone away. This is how the DataTable is created in code, including the cell template:

```
$('#myTable').DataTable({
        data: data,
        columns: [
            {
                data: 'Dimension'
                , render: function (data: any, type: any, obj: any, tbl: any) {
                    //return data;
                    var template =
                        `<div class="container-fluid">
                        <div class="row text-left" style="">
                            <div>
                                <div class="col-md-12">
                                    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="showChildren()"></i>&nbsp;
                                    ${obj.Name}
                                    &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" (click)="addNew()"></i>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>`;

                    return template;
                }
            }
        ]
    });
});
```

The (click) event listeners just get rendered as html and do nothing. How do I get them to work?

Answer (score 2):

You could render the data bound items first as hidden data blocks, then match them to the palceholder templates through jQuery, like below:

HTML:

```
<div class="container-fluid source-data" attr.data-name="{{obj.Name}}" 
    *ngFor="obj in objArray; trackBy: obj.Name" style="display: none;">
    <div class="row text-left" style="">
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus" (click)="showChildren()"></i>&nbsp;
            {{obj.Name}}
            &nbsp;&nbsp;<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign" (click)="addNew()"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
// Initialize jQuery Data Table
$('#myTable').DataTable({
    data: data,
    columns: [{
        data: 'Dimension', 
        render: function (data: any, type: any, obj: any, tbl: any) {
                return `<div id="divTemplate${obj.Name}"></div>`;
            }
        }
    ]
});

// Transfer each DOM data block to the data table templates
$('.source-data[data-name]').each(function () {
    var id = $(this).attr('data-name');
    var html = $(this).attr('data-name').html();
    $('#divTemplate' + id).html(html);
});
```

Comment: While this works for moving the html into the DataTable, the events do not work in the DataTable.

Comment: Instead of the last lines starting with var html = $(this).attr..., try instead $(this).attr('data-name').children().detach().appendTo($('#divTemplate' + id));